# Android Studio, ListView titles has always a single image in all the titles. Can I reduce the x times to 1 time the copy of the images in code

Tags: android, listview

In Android ListView have always a single image repeated in all the titles. How can I reduce a copying of the images in code from x times to 1 time?

Such as the code given below:

```
public class Test1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    String[] fruitNames = {"Apple","Orange","Kiwi","Passion","Banana"};
    int[] fruitImages = {R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
```

In this code I am copying all the times the same image code, that is:

```
int[] fruitImages = {R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right,R.drawable.ic_chevron_right};
```

I want to set a number of repeats such as x (times the drawable image). Is it possible somehow?

The GitHub Project is available from [LarnTech](https://github.com/larntech/listview-display-clicked-item-in-another-activity). In this project, my images are an arrow. I can do this by repeating the things but I am curious if it can be done in a lucid way.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your fruit array alone in the adapter's constructor and use imageView.setResource(R.drawable.ic_chevron_right) to set the drawable

```
 public class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] fruitNames;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] fruitNames) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this. fruitNames = fruitNames;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(fruitNames[position]);//fruitName

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chevron_right); //just set the image in the adapter


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your github project, the images are different in the array.
But here, all  the images are same.

If you don't want to create the array of same images, then you can use just one variable here. Like:

`int fruitImage = R.drawable.ic_chevron_right;`

and it can be used in `getView()` of `CustomAdapter` like

`image.setImageResource(fruitImage);`

But if you've to use different images in each views then you need to use array or go for ArrayList.